# Do deep binding and shallow binding happen in cases besides subroutines are passed as arguments into subroutines?

Tags: closures, programming-languages, computer-science

I am reading Programming Language Pragmatics, by Michael Scott.

The book introduces deep binding and shallow binding   in the case when subroutines are passed as arguments into subroutines

> An additional issue that we have not yet considered arises in
>   languages that allow one to create a reference to a subroutine— **for
>   example, by passing it as a parameter**. When should scope rules be
>   applied to such a subroutine: when the reference is ﬁrst created, or
>   when the routine is ﬁnally called? The answer is particularly important for languages with dynamic scoping, though we shall see that
>   it matters even in languages with static scoping.

As "for example" suggested, does the consideration of deep binding and shallow binding  happen in cases besides the cases when subroutines are passed as arguments into subroutines?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, deep binding and shallow binding happens whenever you create an object, load a class, interface etc...

Comment: Thanks. Could you give some examples?

Comment: I just gave 3... (when an object is created it's being binded to a scope etc)

Comment: I'd say deep vs shallow binding comes to play anytime a function can be called in a scope different from its definition-scope. This is sloppy terminology though (I haven't read the book). Suppose there is a global function *F* that reference a var *x*, also suppose there is a global var *x* and a function *G* with a local var *x*. What *x* does *F* access when called from *G*? Note that *F* has not been passed as a parameter. The same applies to instance variable if applicable and any other similar means (e.g. C lets you hide local vars within nested scopes). If the languages requires ...

Comment: ... variables to be captured by value then even calling the function in its definition scope gives different results for the two bindings if the captured vars are changed between the calls to the function.